# Cannot import views in Django (2.1.4, Python 3.7.0, Win 7)

Tags: python, django

I am building a site with django and cannot import views into my URL file.

My URL file:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path
from django.conf.urls import include
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', include('blog.urls')),
]
```

Error: ImportError: cannot import name 'views' from 'blog' (..\blog\blog__init__.py)

If I try "from blog import views", I get the same error.

If I try "from blogapp import views" (blogapp is the name of the app within the blog foler), I get:

```
RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object.
```

Essentially, it bounces back and forth between line 23 in check_resolver (django\core\checks\urls.py) and line 397 in check (django\urls\resolvers.py).

If I try just: "import views", I get "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'views'"

My project structure:
Main directory is "blog", contains two folders (blog and blogapp) as well as the db.sqlite3 and manage.py files.

Subfolder blog contains **pycache** folder, and these files: **init**.py, settings.py, urls.py, wsgi.py.

Subfolder blogapp contains **pycache** folder migrations folder, and these files:  **init**.py, admin.py, apps.py, models.py, tests.py, views.py.

Both blog and blogapp are in my INSTALLED_APPS in settings.py.

I checked several similarly named questions (and their suggested answers) and could not figure out what is going wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First rename your project folder to something different than the app folder such as blog-project. Then you should have an updated tree as follows:

**blog-project**
-blog (settings.py, urls.py, and wsgi.py in this folder)
--urls.py (See My Example 1)
-blogapp 
--templates
---blogapp
----blogapp_home.html
----index.html
--urls.py (In this file you do from . import views)

When you navigate to the home page Django reads from your root urls.py. Since you have your starting point set to:

```
path('', include('blogapp.urls')),
```

It then loads the urls.py from the new application you created, blogapp. From urls.py in the blogapp folder import your views.

```python
# Example 1 blog-project/blog/urls.py

from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include
from blogapp import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', views.index, name='home'),
    path('blogapp/', include('blogapp.urls')),
]
```

```python
# Example 2 blog-project/blogapp/urls.py

from django.urls import path, include
from . import views

urlpatterns = [

    path('', views.blogapphome, name='blogapp-home'),

]
```

```python
# Example 2 Views blog-project/blogapp/views.py

from django.shortcuts import render

def index(request):
    sometext = 'More Text'
    context = {'text': sometext}

    return render(request, 'blogapp/index.html', context)

def blogapphome(request):
    sometext = 'Some Text Here'
    context = {'text': sometext}

    return render(request, 'blogapp/blogapp_home.html', context)
```

```python
# blog-project/blog/settings.py

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'blogapp.apps.BlogappConfig',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
]
```

Comment: This works although I am a bit confused why we have two url files, it seems like it would be cleaner to have just one?

Comment: When you create a project you start with a ROOT url.py so to speak which really just gets you started. Its the entry point to direct to the urls.py of your applications. Its actually cleaner because of the plug and play functionality of applications in Django. Say you wanted to implement someone elses's application into your project or a previous one you created. It would be an easy integration if all the urls routes for that application were within the urls.py file. As you use Django more your projects will have several applications. Each will have their own urls.py.

Comment: As you dive deeper into Django you will really start to appreciate its organization and simplicity. Its like anything else where after you have several projects completed that you begin to see the connections.